# how to find swipe percentage?

Tags: android, swipe

in my app i am adding a functionality like when user swipes a list item there should be one options displayed in the same row.But if the swipe is more than 30% and less than 50% i have to show option "watch".If the swipe is more than 50% i have to show option "delete". I have done the coding for this. But there is an error in finding the percentage. I am getting % less than 30 only. Given below is my code to find the percentage. Please help me.

```
  DisplayMetrics dm = m_Context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
  screenWidth=dm.widthPixels;
  @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX,
            float velocityY) {

        float startX,endX,distance;
        startX=e1.getX();
        endX=e1.getY();
        distance=Math.abs(endX-startX);
        int swipePercentage=(int)((distance/screenWidth) * 100);
        if(startX-endX<0){
            int pos = list
                    .pointToPosition((int) e1.getX(), (int) e2.getY());

            if (pos >= 0 && temp_position == pos)
                m_Callback.onSwipeItem(true, pos,swipePercentage);
        }
   }
```

Comment: Actually you don't need to cast it to `int`

Comment: Ohh..It was my issue..instead of getting end point x value i was getting start point y value.Sorry